# H2O Stacked Ensemble MOJO not returning value when Deep Learning included

Tags: h2o

For H2O version 3.30.1.1. I create stacked ensembles of two models, one Deep Learning and one XGBoost and export the MOJO. I have two APIs working with other MOJO files, but for these stacked ensembles they fail. The MOJO returns an empty prediction. The models work independently, and it appears that the H2O binary works as well. I'm simply creating the model as:

```
   ensemble = H2OStackedEnsembleEstimator(base_models=[DeepLearningModel, XGBoostModel])
   ensemble.metalearner_fold_column = 'fold_numbers'
   ensemble.train(x=parameters, y=response, training_frame=model_trainer.h2odata)
```

These fail independent of the dataset I'm training on. Also, StackedEnsemble_BestOfFamily model MOJOs fail in the same manner if DeepLearning is included as an algorithm.

Why are do these MOJOs fail to return predictions, and what can I do to stop it? Could Deep Learning be the problem somehow?